# vb gridview header on every page pdf

Tags: pdf, vb6

i have a gridview which display 100 over records. I want to port it to PDF with
ITextSharp.
I managed to do it however, i cannot ensure my column header pend through every page. Cuz the displayed values are too much for my pdf to handle.

Please help THank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Guys thanks alot i have reolved my own question thus ill post the code here

```
pdfTable.HeaderRows = 1
```

By doing this, the gridview in pdf will automatically take the first row as header and append it through all the pages. so if you want you could do 2 or 3 if im not wrong it means first 3 row will appear on all pages thank you